# How to make form data persist on "reload from cache"

Tags: forms, google-chrome, firefox, reload, page-refresh

I'm making a website. It's a simple profile page. I don't have any subpage, I just do 3 divs and change them and css.

But because its a radioset, if you refresh the page from cache (f5) or duplicate the tab, or press back/forward, the form data remains intact so it shows the proper div. This is good behavior. However I only see this in Firefox.

Browsers like google chrome are not keeping the form data on  (f5) refresh from cache but it clears form data (as if it is a reload from server). How can I make form data persist on reload from cache in this browser?

here is the site if you would like to see what i mean: http://noitidart.github.io/

I understand people sometimes want the opposite behavior then I'm looking for. They want form cleared even on reload (as Chrome currently does) but that's easy to ensure in Firefox just stick in a `document.form.reset()` in the head.

Answer (score 1):

Firefoxes restore of form data values is fine on reload (without Shift or CTRl;).
This is missing in Google Chrome.

I found this:
`autocomplete="off"`
https://github.com/pradosoft/prado/issues/642
Perhaps `autocomplete="on"` would make it happen? :) i dont know.
stackoverflow.com uses it too.

Comment: Interesting thank for sharing this direction. I don't know if its a solution, but +1 for giving direction.